# Wix deployment with oracle dlls

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dll, wix

I'm very new with .net applications and I'm trying to deploy a winforms app to many machines (32 and 64 bits) without having to install oracle client in each one.
I'm using oracle 11g with Oracle.DataAccess.dll.
I created two wix projects in my solution (setup and bootstrapper). 
My solution has another 4 projects: MyMainForm project, MyService project, MyDAO project and MyDataModel project.
In MyDAO project I have a reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

**First question:**
Where should I put the Oracle.DataAccess.dll file in my solution to add the reference?
I put in bin\Release folder of MyMainForm project.
Along with oci.dll, oramts.dll, oramts11.dll, orannzsbb11.dll, oraocci11.dll, oraociei11.dll and OraOps11w.dll files.
It worked on my machine but I not sure if this is the right place to put them.

**Second question:**
When I install it on my machine (64 bits) works. But when I install on another machine (also 64 bits) it did not work.
I received the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   MyService.dll Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I believe this is releated to the first question. Maybe the file is in the wrong place.

**Third question:**
I read about Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. For what I read I would use only this dll and not all others dlls and I should not worried about 32/64 bits.
But could I use it with oracle 11g?

I read a lot of things about it on foruns but did not find a good tutorial or similar to make this work.
I being struggling with this for about 3 days now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it, but I'm not sure what was the exact error.

Three things I did:

1 - Two of the six projects were configured to "Any CPU" and the others to "x86", I change the ones with "Any CPU" to "x86" (can't remember which ones were, I believe it was MyService project and MyDAO project, but not sure).

2 - In the .csproj file of MyDAO project, the oracle reference was like this:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86" />
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\MyMainForm\bin\Release\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But the .dll file version I'm using is 4.112.3.0, so I change it to:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess />
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <Private>False</Private>
  <HintPath>..\MyMainForm\bin\Release\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

3 - I change my Product.wxs to include the oracle dlls, like this:

```
  <!-- Oracle libraries -->
  <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\oci.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
    <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\oramts.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
    <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\oramts11.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
    <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\orannzsbb11.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\oraocci11.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
    <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\oraociei11.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Guid="*">
    <File Source="$(var.MyMainForm.TargetDir)\OraOps11w.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
```

This way I don't have to install Oracle Client on each machine.